# How to filter JSON file based on conditions?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, filtering

I have a JSON set of data in Python 3, downloaded from a PDB database with API Services and it is as below:

```
result_json = json.loads(result.text)

result_json

{'data': {'entries': [{'rcsb_id': '4UG0',
    'rcsb_external_references': [{'id': 'EMD-2938'}],
    'struct': {'title': 'STRUCTURE OF THE HUMAN 80S RIBOSOME'},
    'em_3d_reconstruction': [{'resolution': 3.6}],
    'exptl': [{'method': 'ELECTRON MICROSCOPY'}]},
   {'rcsb_id': '4V6X',
    'rcsb_external_references': [{'id': 'EMD-5592'}],
    'struct': {'title': 'Structure of the human 80S ribosome'},
    'em_3d_reconstruction': [{'resolution': 5.0}],
    'exptl': [{'method': 'ELECTRON MICROSCOPY'}]},
   {'rcsb_id': '4UG0',
    'rcsb_external_references': [{'id': 'EMD-2938'}],
    'struct': {'title': 'STRUCTURE OF THE HUMAN 80S RIBOSOME'},
    'em_3d_reconstruction': [{'resolution': 3.6}],
    'exptl': [{'method': 'ELECTRON MICROSCOPY'}]},
   {'rcsb_id': '4V6X',
    'rcsb_external_references': [{'id': 'EMD-5592'}],
    'struct': {'title': 'Structure of the human 80S ribosome'},
    'em_3d_reconstruction': [{'resolution': 5.0}],
    'exptl': [{'method': 'ELECTRON MICROSCOPY'}]},
   {'rcsb_id': '5A2Q',}]}}
```

How do I filter this piece of JSON dictionary structure? For example, I would like to only get results with 'resolution' values that are below 4.
I have tried a few functions but not working as expected.

Comment: Maybe you should change the database query instead to only get the results that you actually want.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a part of a bigger project and I have to work on a fixed set of protein data so I don't have the option to change query criteria

Comment: Okay. So what was the problem when you wrote a loop over the entries where you used an if statement to select only those where the resolution value was below 4?

Comment: I basically only got 'invalid syntax' type of errors so I suppose I simply could not get a proper code to do it

Comment: Well then you need to use correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that but I am seeking help or at least any answers or ideas on how to properly construct this loop with an if statement. Or maybe different functions that can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use **literal_eval** method of **ast** module in order to safely evaluate your dictionary to prepare as a source for ingesting and extracting the desired values such as

```
import json
import ast    
Js= """{
 'data': {'entries': [{'rcsb_id': '4UG0',
    'rcsb_external_references': [{'id': 'EMD-2938'}],
    'struct': {'title': 'STRUCTURE OF THE HUMAN 80S RIBOSOME'},
    'em_3d_reconstruction': [{'resolution': 3.6}],
    'exptl': [{'method': 'ELECTRON MICROSCOPY'}]},
   {'rcsb_id': '4V6X',
    'rcsb_external_references': [{'id': 'EMD-5592'}],
    'struct': {'title': 'Structure of the human 80S ribosome'},
    'em_3d_reconstruction': [{'resolution': 5.0}],
    'exptl': [{'method': 'ELECTRON MICROSCOPY'}]},
   {'rcsb_id': '4UG0',
    'rcsb_external_references': [{'id': 'EMD-2938'}],
    'struct': {'title': 'STRUCTURE OF THE HUMAN 80S RIBOSOME'},
    'em_3d_reconstruction': [{'resolution': 3.6}],
    'exptl': [{'method': 'ELECTRON MICROSCOPY'}]},
   {'rcsb_id': '4V6X',
    'rcsb_external_references': [{'id': 'EMD-5592'}],
    'struct': {'title': 'Structure of the human 80S ribosome'},
    'em_3d_reconsruction': [{'resolution': 5.0}],
    'exptl': [{'method': 'ELECTRON MICROSCOPY'}]},
   {'rcsb_id': '5A2Q',}]}
}"""
data = ast.literal_eval(Js)     
de=data['data']['entries']
for i in list(range(0,len(de))):
    try:
        d=de[i]['em_3d_reconstruction'][0]['resolution']
        if d < 4:
            print('value of the resolution for at step ',i+1,' is : ',d)
    except:
        pass
```

| which prints |
| --- |
| value of the resolution for at step 1 is : 3.6 |
| value of the resolution for at step 3 is : 3.6 |

In the above case, I've demonstrated a method to handle easily your source object if it was a string, whereas considering your object is already evaluated through **json.loads**, you can directly go on with the rest of the code starting from

```
data = json.loads(result.text)
de=data['data']['entries']
    for i in list(range(0,len(de))):
....
....
```

Comment: They have already used `json.loads` to parse JSON properly, no need for `literal_eval`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you soooo much. Exactly what I needed :)